# Groovy: Is there any way to get expected property class name

Tags: groovy

For example: i have a method

```
def someMethod(object){
    //retrieve all properties as key:value pair
    for(prop in object.getProperties()) {
        println(prop.getValue().getClass())
    }
}
```

It works well if property already have value. But if it isn't it returns

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject
```

So is there any way to get expected class name for property?

Answer (score 3):

I figure it out:

```
def someMethod(object) {
    for(prop in object.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        if (!prop.getName().contains("\$") && prop.getName() != "metaClass")
            println(prop.getName() + " " + prop.getType())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably cleaner to do:

```
object.getClass().declaredFields.findAll { !it.synthetic }.each {
    println "${it.name $it.type"
}
```